# How to change the scale of different plots in one go

Tags: python, plot, graph

I am new to python and matplotlib. 
I have a code where I have multiple plots together in the same figure and want to change all of the axis scales to log scales. But when I write this code only the x and y axis of the last plot is changed. How should I make all the axis change their scale for all the plots together.

```
plt.plot(freq3, ps3 ,'y')

plt.plot(freq2, ps2 ,'r')

plt.plot(freq1, ps1 ,'b')

plt.plot(freq0, ps0,'g')

plt.yscale('log')

plt.xscale('log')
```

I also need to add labels to each of the plots separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should solve your problem.

```
freq = [freq3, freq2, freq1, freq0]
ps = [ps3, ps2, ps1, ps0]
labels = ['Label3', 'Label2', 'Label1', 'Label0']
colors = ['y', 'r', 'b', 'g']

for i in range(4):
    plt.plot(freq[i], ps[i], colors[i], label=labels[i])
    plt.yscale('log')
    plt.xscale('log')

# ...
plt.show()
```